# Google+ share link doesn't show Description?

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, share, query-string

I'm using the share link Google+ : `https://plus.google.com/share?hl=fr&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%2F`

I wanted to know why my description  tags are not displayed on the share window. I only see an image, a title, an URL but I can't find any description.

```
<meta content="website" property="og:type">
<meta content="Something great" property="og:title">
<meta content="http://mywebsite.com/" property="og:url">
<meta content="My description blaah." property="og:description">
<meta content="http://mywebsite.com/img/partage.png" property="og:image">

<meta content="Something great" itemprop="name">
<meta content="My description blaah." itemprop="description">
<meta content="http://mywebsite.com/img/partage.png" itemprop="image">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Descriptions are no longer shown for simple shares. Only [interactive posts](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) still show descriptions.